# Query the result of a system procedure of a Sybase-ASE 15.7 database

Tags: sql, database, sybase, sap-ase

Looking at the system procedure **sp_helpartition**, it returns a resultset with the following columns:

1. owner
2. name
3. partitions
4. partition_type

I am looking for a way to query the results of **sp_helpartition**, something like:

**SELECT** name 
**FROM** {RESULT OF sp_helpartition} 
**WHERE** partition_type = 'value'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit  of googling got me [this piece of code](https://gist.github.com/csaar95/26a392e47cbf563eeb6bf1d462d8f4b2), so you can easily extend it with your own condition.
I don't have any other idea how to manipulate the result of `sp_helpartition` within sql.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

You can try this one -: 
Store the result of the stored procedure into a table variable and use that table variable as per your wish.

Comment: Table variables don't exist on ASE's version of Transact-SQL like they do in MSSQL. 

The easy workaround though is to pass in @partitionname as a parameter to the stored procedure  to get a single partition's results rather than using a select.